# (Bug?) Android button responds to hand gesture

Tags: android

I have `Button` in my Android application and I manage two states of affairs using an Enum. The button has two logical states defined by the Enum; `Stopped` and `Recording`.

When the button is clicked while in `Stopped` state, an instance of `AudioRecorder` starts recording the user's voice and the state advances to `Recording`.

When the button is clicked while in `Recording` state, the recording stops and the state goes back to `Stopped`.

Now, sometimes when I start recording then simply wave my hand without making any contact with the phone, the recording stops as if the button was clicked.

I only handle the button click events using the `OnClickListener` interface and nowhere have I setup to receive gesture events.

What is this? Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Maybe screen rotates and activity is recreated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I found the culprit, I forgot to mention that I was using `CountDownTimer` which tends to skip ticks sometimes. The `onFinish()` method of this class was being called too early sometimes coincidentally with my hand over the phone.

I solved it by creating my own Timer class using a `Handler`.